# How do I replace a white or colored background with transparency in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I am working on a Logo and am attempting to make the background transparent. Unfortunately, I have zero graphic design experience and am unable to figure out how to get this done.

Could someone walk me through how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! In vector graphics a white background would simply come from having a white object in the back. Just select it and delete it or choose no fill. But you might have placed or pasted in a rasterized (pixel) image. In that case you should use Photoshop to manipulate the image. Btw: How do you know it's white and not transparent? Have you exported it? Illustrator's background is white by default.

Comment: It's imported from .PDF

Comment: A pdf can contain both vector and raster graphics. What happens if you zoom in? Does the curves stay smooth or can you see pixels?

Comment: Having transparency depends on the output format (GIF, JPG, PNG, TIF, etc.) and the display medium (web browser, PDF, video, PowerPoint, Word, etc.), and how you are layering the object. On a web page, transparency can be achieved by exporting as GIF and setting the background color (white) to be the transparent color. This is a standard export option for GIFs. Understand that raster images can't really be transparent unless the display device/software supports it. For printing, a white background represents the paper, not white ink. Show us the image and what you want to do with it.

Comment: It is a vector graphic yes

Answer (score 1):

When you start a new document, the page appears to be white, but it is in fact transparent with the default settings. Then, let`s say you have this circle (replace with your logo):

[image]

Then, you choose File > Save for Web, choose PNG-24 with 'Transparency' checked and you get a transparent PNG logo. The chess-looking squares behind the circle actually represent the transparent background.

[image]

Lastly, save your work as an AI file, which is again transparent by default, unless you place and actual white box behind the artwork.

Comment: Will that work if the current logo is words on a white background?

Comment: Yes, if you remove any white-filled objects from behind the 'words' and just leave the default white 'page' behind your logo, which just looks white, but it is in fact transparent.

Comment: Hmm, and how could I do the same to a non-white background?

Comment: There is NO transparency if you have a flat color object behind your logo. Easier to answer this if we actually saw this logo.